# Differentiating between feminine and plural

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german

First of all, both *she* and *they* translate to *sie*. In most sentences we can tell them apart by looking at the verb. But I got really confused today while doing an assignment. I need to translate **They are taking their clothes from me**.

Using the little knowledge I have, I translated it to *Sie nehmen von mir ihre Kleidungen*. But this also means **They are taking her clothes from me**.

Would anyone let me know how to translate these two sentences from English to German unambiguously?

Comment: Context will tell, as it does with English _you_. Without further context the possessive _ihre_ will refer to the personal pronoun _sie_ which is the subject of the sentence. Btw., _Kleidung_ doesn’t get a plural ending, but there’s _Kleidungsstücke_. PS: In this case a better and unambiguous, but not literal, translation would be “Ich geben ihnen/ihr ihre [eigene] Kleidung”.

Comment: @Crissov: Ich gebe ihnen/ihr ihre Kleidung. Ich richte meine Waffel auf Sie!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this scenario, context would be used to differentiate the two. There really isn't a way to decide between *ihre* as their and *ihre* as her. In fact, if it weren't written down, you would equally be able to say that sentence translates to "you are taking your clothes from me." If I were speaking and what I was trying to say was ambiguous, I would phrase the sentence like this: 
*Sie nehmen von mir Katjas Kleidung.* In other words, being more specific would solve your problem.